# Tool for preview JavaScript based on my TypeScript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, resharper

I start learn TypeScript. I'm looking for extensions in VisualStudio or Re#, which will show live JavaScript based on TypeScript written by me

Could you recommend something like that? I use VS 2015 with Re#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a tool but you should definitely check https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ as it does what you need.  It's a home website for typescript language.